# Iterate sub object in union type - typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a union type with a sub object containing different properties. Is there a way to accept this union in a function and iterate over it's sub object's keys in a typescript safe way?

```
// TYPES

type A = {
    bools: {
        a: boolean;
        b: boolean;
    };
};

type B = {
    bools: {
        b: boolean;
        c: boolean;
    };
};

type U = A | B;

// ATTEMPTED TYPING

type GetKeyGroups<T> = T extends T ? Array<keyof T> : never;
type keygroups = GetKeyGroups<U['bools']>

// WANTED USE

const a: A = {
    bools: {
        a: false,
        b: false,
    },
};

const test = ( obj: U ) => {
    const bools: U["bools"] = obj.bools
    const keys = Object.keys(bools) as keygroups

    keys.forEach((key) => console.log(bools[ key ]));
}

test(a)
```

This ^ seemed like a good solution until typescript complained that `key` was of type any in `keys.forEach((key) => console.log(bools[ key ]));`

Is there any way to accomplish this in the current version of TypeScript?

Comment: Even if you get the type you're looking for ... if `key` is of type `"a" | "b" | "c"` and `bools` is of type `{a: boolean; b: boolean} | {b: boolean, c: boolean}` ... then you will immediately hit the problem that `bools[key]` is not known to be safe, since for all the compiler knows, `key` is `"c"` but `bools` is `{a: true, b: false}`.  You *might* want to make `test` a generic function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/ND58Rm), but it depends on the use case, and I'm not really sure what that is.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Something like this should work

```
const test = ( obj: U ) => {
    const bools: U["bools"] = obj.bools
    const keys = Object.keys(bools) as (keyof typeof bools)[]

    keys.forEach((key) => console.log(bools[key]));
}
```